# Splitting long row of text/numbers into multiple rows of specific length

Tags: excel

I have a VERY long line of text, thousands long just like this

```
76561197997162298
76561197997094193
76561197996891032
76561197996814030
76561197995825191
76561197995316081
76561197995286134
```

and I would like a simple way to split it into rows of 100 long output someway that I could import into excel, unless excel itself can do it, though I was unable to find a way. As long as I dont have to do any coding, it could be done in any language I can run on a windows PC. If there is some program that does it, I could use that as well. Otherwise I will have to devise some hack job using a macro recorder

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is the best method to do what you were asking! Enjoy

```
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Text-File-Splitter.shtml
```

It's called Text File Splitter 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

used JitBit Macro Recorder with this script
Thanks anyways =)

```
    WAIT FOR USER : 192 : 2 : 0 : 0
Keyboard : ShiftLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : Down : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ShiftLeft : KeyUp
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : ControlLeft : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : X : KeyDown
DELAY : 10
Keyboard : X : KeyUp
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub LongRowImport()

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;C:\pathname\long_text_row.txt", _
            Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .Name = "long_text_row"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 775
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
            .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
End Sub
```

That's a macro derived from Data - Import External Data - Import Data (Excel 2003).

Comment: Seems like it could work, but when ran it only outputs it all in one long row, not sure why. I am also using Excel 2010 but I assume macro's are cross compatable